# Codeigniter white screen of death on models

Tags: php, codeigniter

If there is an error in my model codeigniter will just show a blank page. I have error reporting set to E_ALL and DB debugging turned on.

Is there any way I can get the errors to show up?

Comment: Do you only get this with errors from your model? Do you get output if you only use controllers and views? If you're not getting any output at all it's likely to be a server issue - in which case could you tell us your server setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the .htaccess file the root of your site:

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

i can recommend downloading the uhoh error exception library for codeigniter (taken from kohana) it is very helpful:

https://github.com/dhrrgn/codeigniter-uhoh

you can also check php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Comment: +1 for the uhoh extension, very cool. I need to use this for my next CI project.

Answer (score 1):

I remember getting no error reported if I didn't have the php_mysql module installed and configured for PHP.  Maybe check check the output of the `phpinfo` function to see if the mysql module for PHP is installed.

Thats my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

For linux users: ensure you set `mysqli`

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

in your `database.php` file

Comment: Fixed with this info! Very useful. Thanks you.